# How to retrieve MySQL results from exports in Nodejs to use in main app

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

i'm using the following to build a web app: `nodejs`,`express`,`handlebars` and `mysql`.  I'm trying to get query results from one file **dbconnect.js** to my app file **app.js** via the `exports` object.  I have seen some suggestions to getting query results by using `jade`, but can this be accomplished with this tech stack?

Portion of **dbconnect.js**

```
exports.allBooks=function(req,res){
connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Database connection failed'+err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Connected to the db');
    connection.query("select Title from Books",function(err,result,fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
        connection.end();
    })
});
};
```

Portion of **app.js**

```
var mydb = require('./dbconnect.js');
...
...
app.post('/process',function(req,res){
var myresults=mydb.allBooks(req,res);
console.log(myresults);
res.redirect(303,'/thank-you');
});
```

**myresults** prints out as **undefined**.  Thank you so much for any comments/answers/suggestions.